# Exit script if I click exit button on the form?

Tags: powershell

Im running a pick date calendar function inside a while ($true) loop. So its running constantly.

But I want to kill it if the user clicks the exit button on the form (not in a dialog box). How can I do that?

```
while($true){

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
Function Pick-Date {
  $Cal = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
  $Cal.ShowWeekNumbers = $true
  $Cal.MaxSelectionCount = 1
  $Cal.Dock = 'Fill'
  $Form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
  $Form.text = "Colocar fecha que desea enviar. Y presiona Enter"
  $Form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(656,620)
  $btnSelect = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $btnSelect.Size = "100,100"
  $btnSelect.add_Click({ $Form.close() })
  $btnSelect.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(530,480)
  $btnSelect.Text="ENTER"
  $Form.Controls.Add($btnSelect )
  $Form.AcceptButton = $btnSelect
  $Form.Controls.Add($Cal)
  $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
  [void]$Form.ShowDialog()
  return (Get-Date($Cal.SelectionStart))
}

$fecha = Pick-Date

}
```

Comment: Yeah I want to keep the calendar running despite the user selecting a date.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the

```
 while($true) {}
```

Just write

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
Function Pick-Date {
  $Cal = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
  $Cal.ShowWeekNumbers = $true
  $Cal.MaxSelectionCount = 1
  $Cal.Dock = 'Fill'
  $Form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
  $Form.text = "Colocar fecha que desea enviar. Y presiona Enter"
  $Form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(656,620)
  $btnSelect = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $btnSelect.Size = "100,100"
  $btnSelect.add_Click({ $Form.close() })
  $btnSelect.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(530,480)
  $btnSelect.Text="ENTER"
  $Form.Controls.Add($btnSelect )
  $Form.AcceptButton = $btnSelect
  $Form.Controls.Add($Cal)
  $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
  [void]$Form.ShowDialog()
  return (Get-Date($Cal.SelectionStart))
}

$fecha = Pick-Date
write-host $fecha
```

Unless you want the calendar form open even when the user has enter clicked a date? The version above closes when the user clicks exit or when the user enters a date.

Comment: Dispose of the form when it is no longer used!. Something like `$result = (Get-Date($Cal.SelectionStart)); $Form.Dispose(); return $result`

Comment: The idea its to click on the date execute the rest of the script and re open the calendar until the user use the X button on the form to exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the reason the form is being closed in the FormClosing event, and set a script-scoped variable to prevent reopening:

```
$Script:UserClosed = $false 
while($Script:UserClosed -ne $true){
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
Function Pick-Date {
  $Cal = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
  $Cal.ShowWeekNumbers = $true
  $Cal.MaxSelectionCount = 1
  $Cal.Dock = 'Fill'
  $Form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
  $Form.text = "Colocar fecha que desea enviar. Y presiona Enter"
  $Form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(656,620)
  $btnSelect = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $btnSelect.Size = "100,100"
  $btnSelect.add_Click({ $Form.close() })
  $btnSelect.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(530,480)
  $btnSelect.Text="ENTER"
  $Form.Controls.Add($btnSelect )
  $Form.AcceptButton = $btnSelect
  $Form.Controls.Add($Cal)
  $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
  $Form.Add_FormClosing({
    param( $sender,$e)
    If($e.CloseReason -eq 'UserClosing'){$Script:UserClosed = $true}
  })
  [void]$Form.ShowDialog()
  return (Get-Date($Cal.SelectionStart))
}
$fecha = Pick-Date
}
```